# Feature selection on high frequency data matlab

Tags: matlab, bigdata, feature-selection

I have 1 year of 50Hz data (Wind Turbine), around 100gb. 10min Files, each file has around 70 sensor files. Each sensor variables has around 30.000 data.

I am trying to apply feature selection methods on this data. What worked so far is when I am merging for example 10 sensor where I think they have an influence on the dependent variable. I end up with a matrix of 10 variables and each variable has 30.000 times lets say 6 files so 180.000. And here I only evaluated an hour of data from a whole year.

Is there a possibility to evaluate all my data with featureselection methods?

%This script reads in all data from the workspace and merges the data from
%different files. set of variables is created: Dependent variables - A/A1
%and independent variables res_biege for further work

```
xliste = dir('*.mat'); %dateiinformationen werden ge-speichert 
xanzahldateien = numel(xliste); % Anzahl der gefun-denen .mat dateien 
xnamederdatei =  {xliste.name}; % alle dateinamen im Ordner werden im Array gespeichert

C_Bieg1_060_240_merge = [];
Generatordrehzahl_Anlagengeno_merge = [];
Generatordrehzahl_Triebstrang_merge = [];
Pitchwinkel_Blatt1_merge = [];
Rotordrehzahl_merge = [];
Turmschwingung_X_merge = [];
Turmschwingung_Y_merge = [];
Windgeschwindigkeit_Gondel_merge = [];
Windrichtung_relativ_merge = [];
Wirkleistung_merge = [];
C_Bieg2_150_330_merge = [];


for k=1:1:length(xliste)-1 %Einlesen der daten aus dem Ordner 
load(xnamederdatei{k}); % öffnen der dateien
%cut all sensor values into one vector
C_Bieg1_060_240_merge = vertcat(C_Bieg1_060_240_merge, C_Bieg1_060_240);
C_Bieg2_150_330_merge = vertcat(C_Bieg2_150_330_merge, C_Bieg2_150_330);
Generatordrehzahl_Anlagengeno_merge = vertcat(Generatordrehzahl_Anlagengeno_merge,Generatordrehzahl_Anlagengeno);
Generatordrehzahl_Triebstrang_merge = vertcat(Generatordrehzahl_Triebstrang_merge,Generatordrehzahl_Triebstrang);
Pitchwinkel_Blatt1_merge = vertcat(Pitchwinkel_Blatt1_merge,Pitchwinkel_Blatt1);
Rotordrehzahl_merge = vertcat(Rotordrehzahl_merge,Rotordrehzahl);
Turmschwingung_X_merge = vertcat(Turmschwingung_X_merge,Turmschwingung_X);
Turmschwingung_Y_merge = vertcat(Turmschwingung_Y_merge,Turmschwingung_Y);
Windgeschwindigkeit_Gondel_merge = vertcat(Windgeschwindigkeit_Gondel_merge,Windgeschwindigkeit_Gondel);
Windrichtung_relativ_merge = vertcat(Windrichtung_relativ_merge,Windrichtung_relativ);
Wirkleistung_merge = vertcat(Wirkleistung_merge,Wirkleistung);

end
% clear the workspace except needed variables
clearvars -except C_Bieg1_060_240_merge C_Bieg2_150_330_merge Generatordrehzahl_Anlagengeno_merge Generatordrehzahl_Triebstrang_merge Pitchwinkel_Blatt1_merge Rotordrehzahl_merge Turmschwingung_X_merge Turmschwingung_Y_merge Windgeschwindigkeit_Gondel_merge Windrichtung_relativ_merge Wirkleistung_merge
%cutting down vectors to the same length
C_Bieg1_060_240_merge = C_Bieg1_060_240_merge(1:150000);
C_Bieg2_150_330_merge = C_Bieg2_150_330_merge(1:150000);
Generatordrehzahl_Anlagengeno_merge = Generatordrehzahl_Anlagengeno_merge(1:150000);
Generatordrehzahl_Triebstrang_merge = Generatordrehzahl_Triebstrang_merge(1:150000);
Pitchwinkel_Blatt1_merge = Pitchwinkel_Blatt1_merge(1:150000);
Rotordrehzahl_merge = Rotordrehzahl_merge(1:150000);
Turmschwingung_X_merge = Turmschwingung_X_merge(1:150000);
Turmschwingung_Y_merge = Turmschwingung_Y_merge(1:150000);
Windgeschwindigkeit_Gondel_merge = Windgeschwindigkeit_Gondel_merge(1:150000);
Windrichtung_relativ_merge = Windrichtung_relativ_merge(1:150000);
Wirkleistung_merge = Wirkleistung_merge(1:150000);

%avereging every 5 values
C_Bieg1_060_240_merge = nanmean(reshape( [C_Bieg1_060_240_merge(:);nan(mod(-150000,50),1)],50,[]))';
C_Bieg2_150_330_merge = nanmean(reshape( [C_Bieg2_150_330_merge(:);nan(mod(-150000,50),1)],50,[]))';
Generatordrehzahl_Anlagengeno_merge = nanmean(reshape( [Generatordrehzahl_Anlagengeno_merge(:);nan(mod(-150000,50),1)],50,[]))';
Generatordrehzahl_Triebstrang_merge = nanmean(reshape( [Generatordrehzahl_Triebstrang_merge(:);nan(mod(-150000,50),1)],50,[]))';
Pitchwinkel_Blatt1_merge = nanmean(reshape( [Pitchwinkel_Blatt1_merge(:);nan(mod(-150000,50),1)],50,[]))';
Rotordrehzahl_merge = nanmean(reshape( [Rotordrehzahl_merge(:);nan(mod(-150000,50),1)],50,[]))';
Turmschwingung_X_merge = nanmean(reshape( [Turmschwingung_X_merge(:);nan(mod(-150000,50),1)],50,[]))';
Turmschwingung_Y_merge = nanmean(reshape( [Turmschwingung_Y_merge(:);nan(mod(-150000,50),1)],50,[]))';
Windgeschwindigkeit_Gondel_merge = nanmean(reshape( [Windgeschwindigkeit_Gondel_merge(:);nan(mod(-150000,50),1)],50,[]))';
Windrichtung_relativ_merge = nanmean(reshape( [Windrichtung_relativ_merge(:);nan(mod(-150000,50),1)],50,[]))';
Wirkleistung_merge = nanmean(reshape( [Wirkleistung_merge(:);nan(mod(-150000,50),1)],50,[]))';
%Create a table for correlation analysis & array (matrix)
res_biege = sqrt(C_Bieg1_060_240_merge.^2 + C_Bieg2_150_330_merge.^2);
T = table(res_biege , Generatordrehzahl_Anlagengeno_merge, Generatordrehzahl_Triebstrang_merge, Pitchwinkel_Blatt1_merge, Rotordrehzahl_merge, Turmschwingung_X_merge, Turmschwingung_Y_merge, Windgeschwindigkeit_Gondel_merge, Windrichtung_relativ_merge, Wirkleistung_merge);
A = table2array(T);
A1 = table2array(table(Generatordrehzahl_Anlagengeno_merge, Generatordrehzahl_Triebstrang_merge, Pitchwinkel_Blatt1_merge, Rotordrehzahl_merge, Turmschwingung_X_merge, Turmschwingung_Y_merge, Windgeschwindigkeit_Gondel_merge, Windrichtung_relativ_merge, Wirkleistung_merge));
R = corrcoef(A)
```

Comment: I would start by dimensionality reduction. You can try use PCA to get few virtual sensors from your 70 sensors.

Comment: Yes definitely, there are many things i can apply but i am not sure how to apply it to a few billion of data in different files. I applied some selection tools already after i merged 6 files together and the PC handels that well. but i have a year of data which is 1.576.800.000 per sensor.

Comment: Did you check correlations between sensors? Besides dimensionality reduction you can downsample. For 50Hz I would downsample to ~Hz sRate. Better still, if the dependent variable allows, I would keep only 50Hz per second , or even per file. This should reduce the data amount greatly

Comment: Yes, correlation analysis I did but on 6 files, I will reduce it to one value per 10min now but actually, my plan was to build a model that can reproduce 50Hz data. But I am not sure how to deal with such a large amount

Comment: Yes definetly I will reduce the 70 sensors. But explaining why i reduce each sensor i needed a correlation analysis or some feature selection methods to show that some are redundent or have no influence on the dependent variable but I am not sure how to do this on 1 year data